# How to find a word in a sentence that starts and ends with the same letter?

Tags: python

Is there a way to write "for" loop and "If Else" in python that searches through a sentence and find the number of words that start and end with the same letter?
I've tried writing something like:

```
sentence = "Mom knock the door"

list = sentence.split()
for word in sentence:
    if ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply compare the character at the beginning of the string with the character at the end of the string like so:

```
if word[0] == word[-1]:
```

If it shouldn't be case sensitive, lower the word first by calling:

```
word = word.lower()
```

Comment: It's cleaner to .lower() the original sentence if case-sensitivity isn't a requirement.

Comment: @Jason That is true. However, I just wanted to be sure that the for-loop works for him, as he already split the string at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

```
words_list = sentence.split()
new_words_list = []
for word in words_list:
    if word[0] == word[-1]:
        new_words_list.append(word)

print('Number of words that starts and ends with same letter - {}'.format(len(new_words_list)))
```

Also you can do it with list comprehension:

```
new_words_list = [word for word in words_list if word[0] == word[-1]]
```

If you want not to have it case sensitive use `word[0].lower()` and `word[-1].lower()` instead of `word[0]` and `word[-1]`

Comment: This solution is case-sensitive. The author didn't specify the same case in the question -- only that it is the same letter. I would use .lower() on the original sentence if case sensitivity isn't a requirement.

Comment: The author didn't add if it's required to be case sensitive or not, so I added that option in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are all smart, I prefer to deal with it in functional programming way, like this:

```
sentence = "Mom knock the door"


def is_same_letter_at_begin_end(word):
    return word and word[0].lower() == word[-1].lower()


target_words = list(filter(is_same_letter_at_begin_end, sentence.split()))
print(target_words)
print(len(target_words))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = sentence.split(" ")
count = 0
for word in list:
    lc_word = word.lower()
    if lc_word[0] == lc_word[-1]:
        count +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = sentence.split()
num_words = 0
for i in lst:
    low = i.lower()
    if low[0] == low[len(low)-1]:
        num_words += 1
return num_words
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score 0):

`list` or `set` comprehension case insensitive:

```
sentence = "Mom knock the door, mom"
all_words_count = len([ word for word in sentence.split() if word[0].lower() == word[-1].lower() ])
uniq_words_count = len({word.lower() for word in sentence.split() if word[0].lower() == word[-1].lower()})

print(all_words_count) #=> 3
print(uniq_words_count) #=> 2
```